# error in xml code

Tags: xsd

I am using the code inXML scehma to represent my phone number which is like this:

ABC-JHG

I am getting an error like: values  Abc-JHG is not allowed for element Name.

How should I make it comaptile with my input.

Comment: icyrock.com's answer is correct.  Also consider that that regex will work ONLY for US phone numbers.  Do you want to restrict the content that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\d` is only for numbers, change the second two to `\w`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression that allows non-numeric data.